# #REF error using VLookup and Offset

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros

So I'm running into an issue where I want to pull a few formulas automatically based on what my material type is (I column) and then I'm using a custom module/macro to evaluate my strings as a formula, and using offset to get to the correct cells. I've attached a picture with what's going on as well as the highlighted cell is where I'm getting the #REF error. [image: Attached image that shows the sheet and formulas I'm working on]

Here's the macro just in case you need that. [image: macro]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. And yes, I'm sure this could maybe be done better as a database, but there are other circumstances which are stopping us from doing that at this time, thanks.

Comment: As a test, do you also get the error if you just put the formula straight into V24? And what if you put the text part into eval() without lookup? Note you can save some time by dropping offset and just use `"R"&ROW()&"C"&(COLUMN()-8)` with indirect or better yet just use `INDEX($A$1:$P$100,ROW(),COLUMN(N1))`

Comment: A further suggestion, write your lookup formulae as normal excel formula in your lookup table but always use say the first row `=$N$24 * $O$24 / 12`. Then use FORMULATEXT(INDEX(MATCH(...)...)) instead of VLOOKUP to return to the formula as text. Use that with EVAL(SUBSTITUTE(...,"$24","$"&ROW())) to correct the row offset.

Comment: Ok, I want to try your second suggestion, but I'm confused on how you want me to use the eval(substitute) with the formulatext option. Also, to answer your question, yes, the formula works find if put straight into V24 (as well as your suggestion of INDEX($A$1:$P$100,ROW(),COLUMN(N1))

Comment: Did you use **R1C1** reference style and INDIRECT function to return cell value?

Comment: Great, I suspect using INDIRECT with EVALUATE(...) leads to all sorts of trouble. The problem seems to be related to the apostrophe and equal signs - but I haven't quite figured it out yet. Best actually to just avoid it using INDEX instead (or my SUBSTITUTE method) and your #REF error should be gone.

Comment: As for EVAL(SUBSTITUTE...), you want to write all the formula in your lookup table as normal formula for the first row, so that your lookup table actually computes the numerical answers. `MATCH("HRT",$U$1:$U$100...)` will return the correct row number to lookup the formula. `FORMULATEXT(INDEX($V$1:$V$100, MATCH(...)))` will return formula as text, but with the wrong row number (#24). SUBSTITUTE will replace the wrong row number with relevant ROW(), so that you finally have the correct formula as text string, which you can then EVAL(...).

Comment: Alternatively, write your text lookup formulae using text place holders e.g.  "length * PCS / 12" (strings only, no named ranges). Then `EVAL(...SUBSTITUTE(SUSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(...), "length", $N24), "PCS", $O24), "dim1", $J24)...)`. This method is less CPU intensive and easier to understand, but slightly less accurate in the n'th decimal, as values are converted to text before it is evaluated.

Comment: I was able to get things working using the last suggestion with the less CPU intensive option as I don't need the decimals to be to a true exact decimal. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the text lookup formula with text place holder "length * PCS / 12" as a string, and then changing the QTY values to `=eval(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(I24,$U$4:V$20,2,TRUE), "length", $N24), "PCS", $P24), "dim1", $J24))`gets the correct answer.